# Making Beamer Handout in RMarkdown (removing pauses)

Tags: r-markdown, beamer

Is there a way to convert a Beamer presentation to a handout presentation and remove the pauses? In LaTeX, this can be accomplished by changing the heading from `\documentclass{beamer}` to `\documentclass[handout]{beamer}`. What is the analog in RMarkdown?

One note, I have some slides that are incremental and others that are not, so I have used `>` instead of `incremental: true` in the YAML header to insert my pauses.

Answer (score 4):

Kindly refer to:  https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/beamer_presentation_format.html for more information.

Following this post, all you need to do is amend your YAML header at the top of your RMarkdown document.  Specifically, use `classoption: "your_usual_option"` to pass whatever argument you would usually pass inside `\documentclass[your_usual_option]{beamer}`. Here is how I did it for your specific case:

```
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    keep_tex: true
classoption: "handout"
```

To make sure my suggestion is working, I added the `keep_tex: true` option in the YAML header above and indeed, my .tex file now shows `\documentclass[10pt,ignorenonframetext,handout]{beamer}`.  If I remove the `classoption:` line, then the .tex file shows `\documentclass[10pt,ignorenonframetext,]{beamer}`

**UPDATE:**

I just found another solution, thanks to [How can we pass pandoc_args to yaml header in rmarkdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47290659/how-can-we-pass-pandoc-args-to-yaml-header-in-rmarkdown) Probably more what you were looking for I am guessing?
You can alternatively adjust your YAML header with:

```
beamer_presentation:
  pandoc_args: [
#      "-M", "classoption=a4paper"
      "-M", "classoption=a4paper,handout"
    ]
```

Your resulting .tex file will show the "updated" document class.