# How can we pass pandoc_args to yaml header in rmarkdown?

Tags: r, yaml, knitr, r-markdown, pandoc

I'm using rmarkdown to produce a word (.docx) report. I would like to change the header of the toc. This seems possible as `pandoc_args` can be passed as options in the yaml header in the case of a doc file (1). But I'm not doing it right. Could anyone provide a working example ?

(1) *pandoc.args is included in the rmarkdown possible options and in the pandoc manual, there is a toc-title option*

```
---
title: "yaml header"
author: "cedric"
output:  
  word_document:
   toc: true
pandoc_args: toc-title="Table des matières"
---
# One section
# Another
```

This produces :

[image: document without change in toc_title]

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The title of the table of contents is [document metadata](http://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#variables-set-by-pandoc), so you can set it with YAML metadata block.

```
---
title: "yaml header"
author: "cedric"
output:  
  word_document:
    toc: true
toc-title: "Table des matières"
---
```

Or passed it in with the `-M` command-line flag.

```
---
title: "yaml header"
author: "cedric"
output:  
  word_document:
    toc: true
    pandoc_args: [
      "-M", "toc-title=Table des matières"
    ]
---
```